# sencha touch :: adding multiple classes to buttons

Tags: css, sencha-touch

is there a way to add multiple classes to a panel or button in sencha touch?
I tried to add more than one with "cls:'newClass secondClass'," but it seems I can only add one class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .addCls function for that.

For example:

```
button.addCls('class1 class2 class3');
```

The HTML output of the button will now be:

```
<div id="ext-comp-1064" class="x-button x-button-normal x-button-action class1 class2 class3" style="margin-top: 8px; height: 30px; "><span class="x-button-label" id="ext-gen1116">Label</span></div>
```

Comment: yes, shure, thanx! right. Now I realise that my question was wrong. I wanted to add an additionally class to the iconClass of an button...

Comment: You want to use your own iconClass on a button? // Your own icon .png etc? That's not that difficult either. There are 2 options, configure your own iconClasses via Compass en Sass, or (easier) define your own icons in a style.css. Please say so, I'll post some code then.

Comment: thats nice but thanx. wrong question was answered right. I just change the '.x-button img.x-icon-mask{}' csscode to get what I want.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by passing an array of strings

```
cls: ['class1', 'class2'],
```

see:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-cls